# Mouse does not work on VMWare Oracle 6 Machine

Tags: linux, mouse, vmware, vsphere, oracle-linux

I am using VMWare vSphere and my mouse does not work very well in just one template and clones of it. There are some informations about my problem in below:

---

- The template is an Oracle Linux 6 template.
- I can click randomly (so if I click 20-30 then times it works once).
- VMWare Tools is up-to-date.
- There is no problem on other templates or VMs.
- There is the problem on VMWare desktop client and web client at the
  same time.
- ESXi version is 6.0, vSphere version is 6.0 and OEL version is 6.9

Comment: I downgrade the kernel to 4.1.12-61.1.34 from 4.1.12-94.1.8 and the problem has been solved. I think there is a bug on version 9x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran an update on 2 of my OEL6 servers that are running under ESXi and the latest UEKR4 (4.1.12-103.3.8) fixes the mouse issue!

Roger